# property owned 50/50 between my brother and me

Tags: taxes, deduction

A three family home was given by my mother to me and my brother. We both are 50/50. He resides at the home while I live somewhere else. He and his wife maintain the property and pays for all repairs etc...., I contribute nothing and the house is paid in full. During tax time, can I legally deduct half the cost on the maintenance/repairs/upgrades and depreciation on the property?

Comment: Please edit and add country tag. Tax rules vary per country.

Comment: You want to know if you can claim deductions for costs you didn't pay?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are talking about.  The house isn't part of a business so neither of you can deduct half of normal maintenance and repairs.  It is just the cost of having a house.

The only time this would be untrue is if the thing that you are buying for the house is part of a special deduction or rebate for that tax year.  For instance the US has been running rebates and deductions on certain household items that reduce energy - namely insulation, windows, doors, and heating/cooling systems (much more but those are the normal things).

And in actuality if your brother is using the entire house as a living quarters you should be charging him some sort of rent.  The rent could be up to the current monthly market price of the home minus 50%.  If it were my family I would probably charge them what I would pay for a 3% loan on the house minus 50%.

Going back to the repairs... Really if these repairs are upgrades and not things caused by using the house and "breaking" or "wearing" things you should be paying half of this, as anything that contributes to the increased property value should be paid for equally if you both are expecting to take home 50% a piece once you sell it.

Comment: It's a 3 family. We don't have enough details. If the other 2 units are rented, and our OP is getting the 1.5 rents less expenses, he claims that rent as income and takes the expenses against it. But we don't have the rest of the story. Question as asked can't be answered .

Comment: The question sounded somewhat vague, hence my answer.  Thanks for clarifying, JoeTaxpayer.

Comment: To make matters worse, 2 weeks and OP hasn't returned. So we have an orphaned question, which as it stands, lacks enough detail for a response. A candidate for closure as "unclear what you're asking." In my opinion.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I agree.  Was just answering strictly on info given - assuming there were no renters based on no mention of it.

Comment: The three families I've seen, tough for one family to occupy two units, but anything is possible .

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I would love to have a 3 family for my family.  Actually... you have me thinking as we are house hunting.

Answer (score 1):

ASSUMING you're talking about a property in the United States, the answer generally would be "no".  You aren't actually *paying* any of the expenses for the property and yet you want to take the deductions for doing so?  That's a rather cheeky move, I'd say! (grin)

It probably would lead to some real strife with your brother, since he would have proper claim to those credit on the basis he's the one footing the bills for the property.  Before you do anything like what you're talking about, it might be best to speak with him, because both of you are running the very real risk of an audit, and if that happens then I can guarantee the IRS will slap the daylights out of you for it.  Your brother, I'm sure, is already claiming all of the deductions he can for what he's putting into the property, and on top of that you want to file for your *half*.  What **half** are you referring to, when your out-of-pocket is zero?  So what you're saying is, you think that between you and your brother you should be able to take a credit of 150% of the actual deductions...Sounds like a recipe for disaster to me.

I strongly encourage you to talk to a tax professional, but if you get a different answer to this than what I've already given then I'd be stunned.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!